# Posting via HTTP requests?

Tags: xml-rpc, remote

Is there any way to do autoblogging on WordPress? What I want to do is to submit a new blogging entry through a HTTP request rather than through the WordPress UI. I know that I can do it using email, but I don't want to go through any mail server.

Comment: Use the JSON-API for a more modern approach - http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/ - no extra libraries needed

Answer (score 3):

the XML-RPC protocol can do that for you, look up how to use it with curl: http://shoaibmir.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/using-curl-for-xmlrpc-calls/ and what the actual tags are: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support